# Dynamic Array Formula using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

the problem I am trying to figure out is a bit complicated and detailed but I will try to simplify it with an example.

I am looking to use vba to change the array formula with a conditional statement. An example of what the code would look like is below

```
If (InStr(1, Range("E" & i).Value, "X")) > 0 Then
 With outputSheet
  Range("I" & i).FormulaArray = Sumproduct(('Sheet1'!$A$57:$A$104=$B2)*('Sheet1'!$E$56:$AZ$56=$H2),'Sheet1'!$E$57:$AZ$104)
  End With
  Else [Same code as above for Array formula]
  End If
```

Initially I was using the following code to copy the Array formula down however using that I cannot use a conditional statement where the formula is dynamic according to cells.

```
 Range("G2").AutoFill .Range("G2:G" & OutputLastRow)
```

If however, I can somehow make the $B2 into B&i then that would do the trick for me.

On just a highlevel, the idea was that the output cell would look at some conditions in the same row and different columns and change array formula according to the conditions. It would look at it for each cell and move down until it hits the last row

Any suggestions on how this can be tackled. I hope the problem is clear. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Look into R1C1 syntax.  It it will allow that.

Comment: So in that example would that change to: Sumproduct(('Sheet1'!$A$57:$A$104=R[2]C[i].....?

Comment: NO, If you are going to use R1C1, **ALL** References must be in that syntax: `Sumproduct(('Sheet1'!R57C1:R104C1=RC2...`  There are many tutorials on how to use R1C1.  You are also missing the `""` around the formula: `"=formula"`

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much! Let me try that

Comment: Found this too would be helpful for anyone who comes across this post:
https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/working-with-range-formulaarray-in-vba/